Barrier method: prove $f(\mathbf{x})\geq f(\mathbf{x}(c))-\frac{m}{c}$

Let $f,g_i$ for $1\leq i\leq m$, be convex and differentiable
functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose barrier method is applied
to problem ($P$): $\min f$ subject to $g_i(\mathbf{x})\leq0$ for
$1\leq i\leq m$. And barrier problem $(Q)$: $\min \phi_c(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})+\frac{1}{c}B(\mathbf{x}),B(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^m-\ln(-g_i)$.
Let $\mathbf{x}(c)$ be optimal to $(Q)$.
Show $f(\mathbf{x})\geq f(\mathbf{x}(c))-\frac{m}{c}$

However, $\phi_{c_{k+1}}(\mathbf{x}_{k+1})\leq \phi_{c_{k}}(\mathbf{x}_{k})\implies f(\mathbf{x}_{k+1})+\frac{1}{c_{k+1}}B(x_{k+1})\leq f(\mathbf{x}_{k})+\frac{1}{c_{k}}B(x_{k})$. It seems contradictory to the question. Is there anything wrong?

What’s the contradiction?

$f(\mathbf{x}{k+1})+\frac{1}{c{k+1}}B(\mathbf{x}{k+1})\leq f(\mathbf{x}{k})+\frac{1}{c_{k}}B(\mathbf{x}{k})\implies f(\mathbf{x}{k+1})\leq f(\mathbf{x}k)-(\frac{1}{c{k+1}}B(\mathbf{x}_{k+1})-\frac{1}{c_k}B(\mathbf{x}_k))$

Check out Boyd’s convex optimization book section 11.2.2 “Center path”
https://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf
